# Does sub query in select executes for only 5 recs if offset fetch next is used

Tags: sql-server

This is a dummy query ,  i want to know, the md col query(correlated sub query) will execute for only 5 records or for all records of sales.customer table.

```
    SELECT CustomerID, 
(SELECT TOP 1 Sales.SalesTerritory.ModifiedDate
FROM Sales.SalesTerritory 
WHERE Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID = Sales.Customer.TerritoryID) md
FROM Sales.Customer 
ORDER BY CustomerID OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

yours sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. It executes 15 times.

```
(5 row(s) affected)
Table 'SalesTerritory'. Scan count 0, logical reads 30, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Customer'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyAKE4djx

[image]